# URL Rewrite redirection based on PostAuthenticate results

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, arr

Using Url Rewrite module, I want to drive a rewrite based upon some value retrieved during a custom authentication process.

During the PostAuthenticateRequest I attempt to set the HTTP header with `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("name", "value");` which is visible on the request object before it leaves the HTTPModule.

However in the URL Rewrite, a very basic condition fails since there's no text under the HTTP_name.

```
<rule name="customrule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_name}" pattern=".+" /> <!-- doesn't work -->
    <!-- <add input="{HTTP_name}" pattern=".*" /> works -->
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://someotherdomain/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Changing the pattern on the condition to .* lets the rule pass but the URL comes out as `https:///{R:0}`. If I manually add the `name` Header *before* requesting the resource from the server it is able to find data. Unfortunately I don't have the data on the  until after a request is made.

Can I use headers across the IIS modules?  How can I get the value from the PostAuthenticate to the URL Rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this blog http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/relationship-between-application-request-routing-and-url-rewrite-modules the ARR implementation occurs at some point after the URL Rewrite and is the actual proxy for external servers.

As I understand it, the Url Rewrite module pulls the headers early on in the request pipeline. As such the Url Rewrite module wouldn't have access to the headers. The pipeline continues to execute through Authentication & PostAuthentication and eventually hands over to Application Request Routing the responsibility to be the proxy.